# SSH to wamp server apache / php from Linux Sub-System

Tags: php, linux, apache, ssh

I am trying to ssh to my Wamp Server 3.0.6 installation on Windows 10 from [Linux SubSystem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/install_guide) but it is asking me for a password. Trying to do a mysqldump of all databases but I don't have anymore an apache console so need to use this one. What password would this contain. I tried blank password, my own linux subsystem password but it's not that one.

Linux subsystem

[image]

Comment: By the way, 127.0.0.1 is the local loopback adapter on the Linux machine, so you are trying to connect to Linux machine from the Linux machine... That won't work ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not be able to SSH to the WAMP installation. SSH is something available from within the OS (not normally in Windows but in Linux). So on your Linux machine you have a SSH server installed and this allows you to connect to it via SSH.

What you want to do, is use the MySQL client on the Linux machine to access the MySQL server that is running on the Windows Machine.

For this you firstly need to ensure that the Windows machine has port 3306 open in the firewall and that the MySQL server has a user like 'user'@'%' or 'user'@'linux.machine.ip'.

Then on the Linux machine you can do:

```
mysqldump -u user -p -h windows.machine.ip database > backup.sql
```

That being said, it's likely going to be easier for you to run this command on the Windows machine:

```
mysqldump -u root -p database > backup.sql
```

I have not used WAMP in years but the MySQL client software is in something like wamp/bin/mysql, look for mysqldump.exe and from this folder can run the above command in command prompt.

As you'd not need to configure remote access to the MySQL server from within Windows. You can then just SFTP into the Linux box and upload the file or SCP to copy the file from Windows to Linux.

Regarding the default password for your MySQL install, it should be root with no password but bear in mind that the MySQL server needs a user account with remote access.

Also, if you're running that Linux box in a VM on the Windows box, check out Samba shares as you could share the Linux file system with the Windows machine, would make it easy to copy things back and fourth.

Comment: `mysqldump -u root -p database > backup.sql`  - this is what I need to do but wamp doesn't have apache console, if I do ps -faux on linux Subsystem I can find WAMP, but netstat -tulpan doesn't show anything, What would be the ip address of the windows.machine? whatsmyipaddress.com?

Comment: @user3467855 Look at my note below the line. You don't need apache console whatever that is. In windows command prompt, you will have to cd c:/wamp/bin/mysql/...whatever else to get to the directory that contains the mysqldump.exe file. Then you can run the command and it will output the .sql file to the same folder.

Comment: @user3467855 Google will give you the machines public IP if you search the term: `my ip`. On linux you might have to use curl or check `ifconfig` output.

Comment: @user3467855 See here: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/25599/mysql-db-import-export-command-line-in-windows